# Insert all post IDs in new database table

Tags: php, query-posts, hooks, functions, mysql

I have a plugin which creates a new database table. Upon activating the plugin is there a way to insert all my posts ids into that table?

Right now I'm using an action hook to immediately insert the id of new posts I publish.

```
function transfer_post_id($post_ID)  {
global $wpdb;
   if (!($wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_id FROM $my_table WHERE post_id = $post_ID" ) ) ) { //if post id not already added
      $wpdb->insert( $my_table, array( 'post_id' => $post_ID ) );      
   }
   return $post_ID;
}

add_action ( 'publish_post', 'transfer_post_id' );
```

However there are posts before activating the plugin that I need a way to insert without manually updating each one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like so:

```
INSERT INTO $mytable (post_id)
SELECT ID
FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
LEFT JOIN $mytable as dup_check
ON dup_check.post_id = posts.ID
WHERE dup_check.post_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this one, I was a bit in a hurry while answering.

Answer (score 5):

You can design your table in such a way that an ID can only exists once by using a key. You can then run a insert into query that selects existing ID values directly with a subselect.

Like so ([credits Denis](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4900/insert-all-post-ids-in-new-database-table/4904#4904)):

```
INSERT INTO $mytable (post_id)
SELECT ID
FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
LEFT JOIN $mytable as dup_check
ON dup_check.post_id = posts.ID
WHERE dup_check.post_id IS NULL;
```

Check the MySql manual regarding the syntax of the [INSERT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry! I lost login please forgive me, apparently I used an incorrect email. I'll contact the forum admin to see how I can recover my username..

Denis thanks for the code!

I'm using it like so

```
   $my_table = $wpdb->prefix . "rated_posts";

   $wpdb->query( "INSERT INTO $my_table (rated_post_id)
                SELECT ID
                FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
                LEFT JOIN $my_table as dup_check
                ON dup_check.rated_post_id = posts.ID
                WHERE dup_check.rated_post_id IS NULL" );
```

I deactivated the plugin and upon activation to test, I get

> The plugin generated 663 characters of
>   unexpected output during activation.
>   If you notice “headers already sent”
>   messages, problems with syndication
>   feeds or other issues, try
>   deactivating or removing this plugin.

I have wp_debug on but I'm not getting any detailed errors.